# How to get IMAP Host name from email address in java?

Tags: java, email, imap, host

I am trying to connect to ISP mail server by using IMAP protocol in java.
My requirement is client provides mail addresses, username and password.
I have to connect the mail Server and store conent of the message to the database.
Here the mail address may belongs to any ISP.

The **javax.mail.server** has method **connect(String host,String UserName,String password)**.

My problem is different ISPs and their sub-domains have different host addresses.

For instance

*gmail* host address is *imap.gmail.com*

*yahoo* host address is *imap.mail.yahoo.com*

*yahoo Uk* host address is *imap.mail.yahoo.co.uk*

How to get host address by reading the provided email address?

like by looking at abc@gmail.com, i can find it belongs to gmail domain, From the domain how can i find host address?

kindly suggest me the best approach, I am ready to user any other protocols like POP, as long as it satisfies my requirement.Suggest me if any alternative exists also.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Determine POP/IMAP server from email address](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2115771/determine-pop-imap-server-from-email-address)

Answer (score 0):

There's no standard way of obtaining that information.

You can try to mimic Mozilla in their [autoconfiguration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Thunderbird/Autoconfiguration), or follow [RFC 6186](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6186) which provides a useful and standard-compliant way of what you're looking for. However, these mechanisms are voluntary, their adoption varies and you cannot rely on them at all.